# BFS, trying to find the longest way between nodes

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

Currently I'm working with an assignment (BFS), where I am supposed to find the longest way between two nodes. Notice that I'm working with both a queue-class and a node-class, the node-class is called `Word` in my assignment. The words are 3-letter words, and I currently have a method (longestway) that returns the longest path from a given word to its smallest child.

The problem is, I want to implement this so that it returns the longest path from any word in a list to its smallest child, and then returns the longest of all those paths.

The code I have right now is working but it's taking way too long time, I need help to speed this one up.

My code is currently looking like this:

```
def printpath1(start):
    ordet=longestway(setlista(),start)
    path=[]
    p=ordet
    while p is not None:
        path.append(p.ordet)
        p=p.parents
    path.reverse()
    #print (path)
    return len(path)


def ordpar(lista):
    s=lista
    a=[]
    for elem in s:
        if a[0]<printpath1(elem):
            a.pop(0)
            a.append(printpath1(elem))
    print(a)
```

`printpath1` is currently working fine, but `ordpar` is taking way too long to run, and I need help to speed it up.

Comment: Are you sure this is your _exact_ code? First `a = []`, then without adding anything to it, you are trying to access `a[0]` which should give an `IndexError`. Also why are you even creating `s` _if_ this is your _exact_ code? You are not using `lista` anywhere so you can just use it instead of creating a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to stop removing elements from the head of the list, since all you do is print, and introduce an offset variable. Also, you're calling `printpath1` twice with the same argument, making twice as much as necessary calculations.

```
offset = 0
for elem in lista:
    pp1 = printpath1(elem)
    if a[offset] < pp1:
        a.append(pp1)
        offset += 1
print(a[offset::])
```